# Interact with view of a specific item in a custom ListView

Tags: java, android, listview, baseadapter

I am using a custom BaseAdapter to create a custom list. What I'm trying to do is have a public function outside of getView(), in this example **setName()**, that can interact with a view of a specific item on the list.

For example calling setName(1); should make invisible the TextView of the second item on the list.

Thank you in advance.

```
public class ListAdapterNew extends BaseAdapter {
private int size;
private Context context;
private ViewHolder viewHolder;

String[][] data;

ArrayList<DataModel> listArray;


public ListAdapterNew(Context context, String[][] data, int size) {
    listArray = new ArrayList<DataModel>(size);
    for(int i=0;i<size;i++){
        listArray.add(new DataModel(i));
    }
    this.context=context;
    this.data=data;
    this.size=size;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return listArray.size();    
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int i) {
    return listArray.get(i);    
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int i) {
    return i;                   
}

public int getViewTypeCount() { return getCount(); }

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {

    return position;
}

private static class ViewHolder
  {
    TextView number,name;
  }



@Override
public View getView(int index, View view, final ViewGroup parent) {
    if (view == null) {
        LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater) parent.getContext().getSystemService(
                Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        view = li.inflate(R.layout.main_user_list_item, parent, false);

        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        viewHolder.number = view.findViewById(R.id.main_list_number);
        viewHolder.name = view.findViewById(R.id.main_list_name);
        
        view.setTag(viewHolder);
    } else {
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        viewHolder.number.setText((index+1)+")");
        viewHolder.name.setText(data[index][0]);
    }

    view.setClickable(true);
    view.setFocusable(true);


    return view;

}

public void setName(int index){
    viewHolder.name.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

The answer was simple. I use a public function inside the ListAdapterNew to update the data[][] and call notifyDataSetChanged(); on the adapter.

There is also a small change in the getView() of the adapter that allows the view to update when items become visible, as shown below.

```
if (view == null) {
    LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater) parent.getContext().getSystemService(
            Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    view = li.inflate(R.layout.main_user_list_item, parent, false);

    viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
    viewHolder.number = view.findViewById(R.id.main_list_number);
    viewHolder.name = view.findViewById(R.id.main_list_name);
    
    view.setTag(viewHolder);
} else {
    viewHolder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
}


if (view != null){
    viewHolder.number.setText((index+1)+")");
    viewHolder.name.setText(data[index][0]);
}
```

Function that updates the data

```
public void updateIcons(int index, int data){
    this.icons[index]=data;
}
```